# Preflight Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, angular5

I'm having CORS trouble with my ASP.NET Core web app that is deployed as an Azure App Service. The front end is deployed as a different app service. When I try to access the Api from the front end I get this following error.

> Failed to load
>   https://chatclassifier.azurewebsites.net/chatcontroller/getchatData:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response
>   is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin
>   'https://chatclassifierangularfrontend20180924084838.azurewebsites.net'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests
>   initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials
>   attribute.

I am using some cookies to pass data between client and server.

I have set up more CORS policy in ASP.NET Core up as follows in Setup.cs

Configure Services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
               builder =>
               {
                   builder
              .WithOrigins("https://XXXXXXXXXXangularfrontend20180924084838.azurewebsites.net")
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowCredentials();
               });
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        });
}
```

Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
    };

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
    }

    app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
    app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ApiExceptionHandling));
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I have not added any other CORS related code anywhere else in my API code. I have tried adding the CORS "AllowAllHeaders" attribute to my controller but this also did not work.

In addition I have added the following line of code to my web app config in Azure under CORS.

[image]

Obviously I have changed the URL name to include XXXXXX and have ensured they are the same in both my Azure Portal and Web App Code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should not combine the Azure App Service CORS config with config in code. If you enable CORS on the app service, your CORS configuration is basically ignored in code.

Comment: @juunas I wish you had submitted that as an answer so I could upvote you. It's not at all obvious from the Azure interface that you shouldn't configure CORS in both places.

Comment: Done, I added the answer 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not combine the Azure App Service CORS config with config in code. If you enable CORS on the app service, your CORS configuration is basically ignored in code.

This is due to App Service intercepting the OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out whyall my settings in the code were being ignored.